# Sull'uso della locuzione 'ad interim'

Tags: word-usage

[Ad interim:](http://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_interim) :

> - La locuzione latina ad interim significa "per ora" (interim significa "frattanto", "nel frattempo"). È utilizzata per indicare che una determinata funzione o carica è assunta provvisoriamente da una persona, nell'attesa della nomina di un titolare.

È corretto usare l'espressione 'ad interim' con riferimento a cose? Ad esempio:

- il vecchio edificio è ad interim la sede del Partito.
- questo è il regolamento ad interim della nuova scuola.

Comment: Sinceramente, preferirei *provvisorio*.

Comment: Ad interim si usa molto nel gergo istituzionale.

Answer (score 3):

"Ad interim" è una locuzione latina che, come scritto, significa nel frattempo, ma nell'utilizzo moderno, si usa solo per indicare una carica provvisoria.
Per le cose è più adatto provvisorio.